# Check the content of each textview from a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview,and each item consists of 3 different textviews. I need to check if the content of the third textview has a specific value.

Any ideas about how to do this? I think it should be implemented inside the adapter class.

```
public class CustomAdapterMenu extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItem> implements View.OnClickListener{

TextView adapter_nrItm=null;
Button adapter_minus=null;
Button adapter_plus=null;


public CustomAdapterMenu(Context context, ArrayList<MenuItem> items) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_item, items);
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_items, parent, false);

    MenuItem menuItem=getItem(position);
    String item=menuItem.getItem().toString();
    String type=menuItem.getType().toString();
    String price= String.valueOf(menuItem.getPrice());



    TextView adapter_item=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
    TextView adapter_type=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
    TextView adapter_price=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    adapter_nrItm=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nrItm);
    ImageView adapter_image=(ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    adapter_plus=(Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    adapter_minus=(Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    adapter_item.setText(item);
    adapter_type.setText(ingredients);
    adapter_price.setText(price);
    adapter_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);


    return customView;

}
}
```

Comment: can you post some snippet?

Comment: @ArpitPatel I just added some snippet . The point is to obtain an array of those items which are of a certain type. The type is changing when you press the buttons .

Comment: What you want to check ? price??

Comment: when you found specific value then what you wanna to do?

Answer (score 0):

It almost definitely should be implemented in the adapter owner.  But the big question is-  do you want to check the views on screen, or all the items in the list?  If its the second, the adapter probably shouldn't even be involved-  just keep a reference to the array and iterate over it.

Comment: If it's in a list, they won't all have text views. That's the way a list works- view recycling. Only the rows on screen have views

Answer (score 0):

In your **MenuItem** class  **getPrice()** method gives you return integer value (price)

So you have to check that value using if condition.

```
 public CustomAdapterMenu(Context context, ArrayList<MenuItem> items) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_item, items);
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_items, parent, false);

    MenuItem menuItem=getItem(position);
    String item=menuItem.getItem().toString();
    String type=menuItem.getType().toString();

    if(menuItem.getPrice()==YourSPecificValue){

      Your code what you wanna to do.
    }

    String price= String.valueOf(menuItem.getPrice());



    TextView adapter_item=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
    TextView adapter_type=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
    TextView adapter_price=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    adapter_nrItm=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nrItm);
    ImageView adapter_image=(ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    adapter_plus=(Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    adapter_minus=(Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    adapter_item.setText(item);
    adapter_type.setText(ingredients);
    adapter_price.setText(price);
    adapter_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);


    return customView;

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the TextView method getText(),it returns the text the TextView is displaying and use it according to your need.It must be implemented in the adapter class.

Comment: Something like:     public boolean checkForText(){
        if (adapter_nrItm.getText().equals"Is of type A")){
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }                                                                                                                   I have this function in my adapter class but I can't see how to implement it outside the class, to check each element of my listview. I want to obtain an array of each items of type A..

Comment: @Mada Make the adapter class an inner class .You can pass the adapter_nrtm.getText() to the function.The function definiation will be - public boolean checkForText(String str){if(str.equals("Is of type A")){return false;} else return true;}